# Mysql to Mongo Data Population

Tags: php, mysql, mongodb

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [MySQL export to MongoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3180709/mysql-export-to-mongodb)
>   [How do I set up replication from MySQL to MongoDB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3801171/how-do-i-set-up-replication-from-mysql-to-mongodb)

We have developed one project by using PHP / MySQL / MongoDB. But we are not able to take a record directly from MySQL to MongoDB server. Every five mins once we are taking records from MySQL and update the records in Mongo by using PHP. Instead of this any other possibilities we can take it a records directly from MySQL to Mongo.

Please share the information for our references.

Comment: Look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3180709/mysql-export-to-mongodb and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6251548/converting-database-from-mysql-to-mongodb

Comment: @JanS I don't think the poster is asking about converting a database, so much as replicating data.

Comment: Hmmm.. On closer reading, yes - though this should be merged with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3801171/how-do-i-set-up-replication-from-mysql-to-mongodb

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to set up [replication from MySQL to MongoDB using Tungsten Replicator](http://code.google.com/p/tungsten-replicator/wiki/TRCHeterogeneousReplication#MySQL_to_MongoDB_Replication).